# Adding properties to be used in XAML dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

is it possible to add dynamic properties to be used in a different class? I mean for example I created a "Leave feedback" button, and when I click it, I want it to send the name of that person to the server. And I want to put the name of those persons when I define those buttons, like:

```
private void LeaveFeedback(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Button btn = sender as Button;
    // I actually do not know how to access that property as well.
    // Maybe something like a dictionary to specify the dynamic properties as `PropertyName: PropertyValue` pair would be efficient.

}
```

```
<Button Click="LeaveFeedback" FeedbackPerson="some_person" UserID="some_person_id" .../>
<Button Click="LeaveFeedback" FeedbackPerson="some_person_2" UserID="some_person_2_id" .../>
```

and so on.

How can I do that? Should I declare a specific control?

Comment: Build a person viewmodel to hold the data. Template out into a button and whatever you need per person.

Comment: Have you looked at attached properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `Tag` property to an instance of a custom or anonymous type:

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
btn.Tag = new { FeedbackPerson = "some_person", UserID = "some_person_id" };
```

Retrieval is flexible but untyped and fragile:

```
dynamic tag = btn.Tag;
string feedbackPerson = tag.FeedbackPerson.ToString();
string iserID = tag.UserID.ToString();
```

A more elegant solution would be create two [attached properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) that you can set and get like this:

```
Behavior.SetFeedbackPerson(btn, "some_person");
string feedbackPerson = Behavior.GetFeedbackPerson(btn);
```